# Spring consume rest json web-service error

Tags: java, spring, rest, webservices-client

below code cause error

```
public ArrayList<model.SampleObject> getObjectByNameGet(String name) {

    final String uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/example/{name}" ;


    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", name);


    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<SampleObject[]> responseEntity = null;
    try {
        responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, SampleObject[].class,map);
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        String errorpayload = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
        throw e;
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    model.SampleObject result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, model.SampleObject.class);
    SampleObject resultOut[] = responseEntity.getBody();

    ArrayList<SampleObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<SampleObject>(Arrays.asList(resultOut));
    return arrayList;

}
```

on this line:

```
responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, SampleObject[].class,map);
```

but service is live and reachable, its local:
[service is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcjtt.png)

error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/example/m":Permission denied: connect; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:543)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:497)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:258)
code.Client.getObjectByNameGet(Client.java:32)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:146)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to intellij VM Options also with no luck.

Whats the cause of error?
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you seen `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` in logs?

Comment: In provided error log, there is java.net.SocketException: Permission denied, See line 1 of error logs

Comment: It means you need credentials to access the REST service, add it as part of headers then you will get the response I believe.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned before, Rest server is local at localhost:8080 address, so there is no special permission required for it, also its reachable through browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after long google and study, I found root of the problem.
there is a bug in window 8 that cause java socket failed to connect to any URL.

there was no problem in windows 7 tests.